# Is a span tag with a href attribute considered valid?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Here is an example:

```
<span href="http://www.example.com">
```

However. [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) says:

> Error: Attribute href not allowed on element span at this point.

So do you guys think it's valid? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think the W3 Validator answers you quite clearly here. Things like this won't produce any error displayed, but still not considered valid

Comment: Not logical span has href according to W3.
Actually here span is a DOM element and you can just attach href attribute that do not work but can contain data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, that is pretty clear…

But if you want it to behave like a link, you can wrap it in an anchor tag, such as

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com"><span>My span is a link !</span></a>
```

Or the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

[Span tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) does not use any other attributes but [global](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp) ones.

There is no logical reason for span to contain href which is an unique attribute of `<a>` tag.

If you need to keep an url in span you should consider using HTML5 data attributes instead. For instance:

```
<span data-url="http://www.example.com">
```

Read more about data attributes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

Answer (score 1):

As W3 Validator is telling you, `href` attribute is not valid on an `span` element.

However, that's strictly speaking. HTML is a very flexible scripting language that allows you to add a lot of things that are not defined in the language, which then will be simply ignored.

So according to that, adding an `href` attribute on an `span` element is valid, but will not work as a real `href` attribute and will be simply ignored. It is then up to you to provide mechanism (mostly via JavaScript) to utilize the attribute.

Programmers have used this fact/feature since the old days of HTML. However, it is now established as a standard using the `data` attribute, so it is advisable that you use it instead. Something like this:

```
<span data-url="http://www.example.com"></span>
```